# How can I get the indexPath of UIButton in a customized tableViewCell?

Tags: iphone

I created a tableViewCell the include an image, two text labels and a uibutton.
The button is allocated to an action method (e.g. viewButtonPused:sender).

I'm used to handle row selection with tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: so I could tell which row was selected. But with the uibutton and its action method .... How can I tell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a delegate on the class associated with the Cell's prototype.

// MyCell.h

```
@protocol MyCellDelegate
- (void)buttonTappedOnCell:(MyCell *)cell;
@end

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyCellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

// MyCell.m

```
@implementation MyCell

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
        [self.delegate buttonTappedOnCell:self];
    }
}
@end
```

Now go to the class you want to make the Cell's delegate. This is probably going to be a UITableView subclass. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method make sure you assign the delegate of the Cell to self. Then implement the method specified in the protocol.

```
- (void)buttonTappedOnCell:(MyCell *)cell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    int row = indexPath.row;
}
```

**Or if you would prefer a blocks based approach:**

// MyCell.h

```
typdef void(^CellButtonTappedBlock)(MyCell *cell);

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell 
@property (nonatomic, copy) CellButtonTappedBlock buttonTappedBlock;
@end
```

Then in your tableView's dataSource:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = ....
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [cell setButtonTappedBlock:^(MyCell *cell) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [weakSelf.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        // Do stuff with the indexPath
    }];

}
```

Comment: But How can we pass section too?

Comment: @ShreeshGarg I've updated my answer with the proper way this should be done.

Answer (score 17):

If the button's target is the `UIViewController`/`UITableViewController` or any other object that maintains a reference to the `UITableView` instance, this will do nicely:

```
- (void)viewButtonPushed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = button.superview; // adjust according to your UITableViewCell-subclass' view hierarchy
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    // use your NSIndexPath here
}
```

Using this approach will let you avoid extra instance variables and will work fine in case you have multiple sections. You need to have a way to access the `UITableView` instance though.

**Edit:** as someone pointed out in the comments below, this approach broke in iOS 7. If you're still interested in using this approach over tags, be sure to find the `UITableViewCell` instance correctly, i.e. by looping through the superviews until you find one.

Comment: Oh I like that way much better then using tags.

Comment: Much better way of doing this kinda thang. I was looking for some help with this, as I have a button which simply removes the table row (hence the indexPath.row gets changed, but the tag remains the same!). +1

Comment: the tag solution is good, but this is perfect when you have multiple sections in your tableview

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Classic example why, with iOS 7 Apple changed the view hierarchy, this will now not work.

Comment: Good point, CW0007007. Since UITableViewCell view hierarchies are now deeper, this won't work anymore for iOS 7. Still, I find the tag approach really annoying, especially in cases of dynamic data since you'd always need a way to map a tag to a cell. And since cells are re-used, this will likely break at some point, too.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is voted up so much. It doesn't even answer the OP's question. If you have access to self.tableView then you have the indexPath. His question was how you access it when you're in a UITableViewCell subclass and you have a button buried in there. This is a whole different issue.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but I find this method best as it is free from superView calls (and thus when Apple change the view hierarchy with new os versions it is left unaffected) and doesn't require subclassing or use of cumbersome tags that can get messed up when the cell is reused.

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    CGPoint location = [sender convertPoint:sender.center toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ...
   [cell.customCellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customCellButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [cell.customCellButton setTag:indexPath.row];
}

- (void)customCellButtonTapped:(id)sender {
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d", button.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have directly added elements on the cell itself (which you shouldnt) -

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[sender superview] ];
```

If you have added elements on the contentView of the cell (which is the proposed way)

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview] ];
```

Answer (score 0):

define one class variable `int SelectedRow;` inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` assign value to it like 
SelectedRow = indexPath.row;

use this SelectedRow variable in side your action method `viewButtonPused:sender`

Comment: Thanks, but didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called unless I touch the row and not just the button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the button as a subview of the cell set it to be [`cell.accessoryView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryView).
Then use [`tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:) to do your stuff that should be done when a user taps this button.

Comment: Sounds interesting. 
I've already used the 'Tag' solution by now.
I'll try this one next time.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that I use now is to subclass UIButton and add a property of type NSIndexPath.
On `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I assign the value of indexPath and its available at the action method.