# Selection on UIButton not Working in my tableView with CustomCell

Tags: ios, tags, uibutton, parse-platform

I'm having problems with my and my TableView Cell Custom.

I state that I am using Parse.com for saving data.

In a nutshell I have a table view with a custom cell that contains a button ...

The actions of this button are divided into two delegates

- (void) addFriendUserButtonPressed: (UITableViewCell *) customCell;
- (void) removeFriendFromList: (UITableViewCell *) customCell;

The first method saves some data to the database the second method deletes them

The user clicks on the button of the first cell and change the image on the button ... 
Scrolling the tableView I noticed that the image changes on other buttons that have not been used ... change them automatically to all ... Sorry if I could not express myself well but they are 6 hours trying to find solutions. ..

I am sure that with the tag would solve but I do not know which method to use ... I'll post the code I'm using

This is the method of button in custom cell class

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (sender == self.addUserButton) {


        if (!self.userSelected) {

            self.userSelected = YES;
            self.addUserButton.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            [self.delegate addFriendUserButtonPressed:self];

        }

        else {

            self.userSelected = NO;
            self.addUserButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

            [self.delegate removeFriendFromList:self];

        }





    }
else if (sender == self.seeProfileButton) {
        NSLog(@"Set  ");
        [self.delegate profileUserButtonPressed:self.itemText];

    } else if (sender == self.contactUserButton) {
        NSLog(@"CONTATTO  ");
        [self.delegate contactButtonPressed:self.itemText];

    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"Bottone Sconosciuto");
    }
}
```

This is the two methods present in viewcontroller containing the tableView.

```
-(void)addFriendUserButtonPressed:(UITableViewCell *)customCell  {


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewFindUser indexPathForCell:customCell];

    PFObject *richiesta = [PFObject objectWithClassName:NPFriendClass];

    if (!isFiltered) {

        PFUser *userFiltered = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [richiesta setObject:userFiltered forKey:NPFriend_AUser];
        [richiesta setObject:userFiltered.objectId forKey:@"OBJECT_USER_ID"];
        [richiesta setObject:userFiltered.username forKey:@"Username"];
        [richiesta setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:NPFriend_DaUser];
        [richiesta setObject:@"Richiesta In Attesa" forKey:NPFriendRequestStatus];
        [richiesta saveInBackground];

        NSLog(@"AMICO: %@", richiesta);
    }


    else {

        PFUser *userNotFiltered = [self.userFiltrati objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [richiesta setObject:userNotFiltered forKey:NPFriend_AUser];
        [richiesta setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:NPFriend_DaUser];
        [richiesta setObject:@"Richiesta In Attesa" forKey:NPFriendRequestStatus];
        [richiesta saveInBackground];

    }

}

-(void)removeFriendFromList:(UITableViewCell *)customCell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewFindUser indexPathForCell:customCell];

    PFUser *userFiltered = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:NPFriendClass];
    [query whereKey:NPFriend_DaUser equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query whereKey:NPFriendRequestStatus equalTo:@"Richiesta In Attesa"];
    [query whereKey:@"OBJECT_USER_ID" equalTo:userFiltered.objectId];
    [query includeKey:NPFriend_AUser];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if(!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"ELIMINATO: %@", object);
                [object deleteInBackground];
            }
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];


}

-(UITableViewCell * )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    NPCustomFindUserCell *cell =[tableViewFindUser dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.delegate = self;


    if ([self.cellsCurrentlyEditing containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [cell openCell];
    }

    if (!isFiltered) {


        PFObject *object = [userArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.user_photoProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"];
        cell.user_photoProfile.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.user_photoProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
        cell.user_photoProfile.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.user_photoProfile.file = [object objectForKey:NPUserKey_PHOTOPROFILE];
        [cell.user_photoProfile loadInBackground];


        NSString *nameText = [object objectForKey:NPUserKey_NOMECOGNOME];
        cell.label_UserNomeCognome.text = nameText;
        cell.itemText = nameText;

    }

    else {

        PFObject *OggettiFiltrati = [userFiltrati objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

             cell.user_photoProfile.file = [OggettiFiltrati objectForKey:NPUserKey_PHOTOPROFILE];
               cell.user_photoProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"];
               [cell.user_photoProfile.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
               [cell.user_photoProfile  .layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
               cell.user_photoProfile.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
               [cell.user_photoProfile loadInBackground];

        NSString *str = [OggettiFiltrati objectForKey:NPUserKey_NOMECOGNOME];
        cell.label_UserNomeCognome.text = str;
        cell.itemText = str;

    }

       return cell;
     }
```

Comment: Which line changes the image you're talking about?

Comment: I'm sorry my brain is now completely dead :( image does not change is the tint color of the button that changes in the custom cell ... forgive me

Comment: You get this result because of cell reuse. You shouldn't change the state of any UI element in a cell (label text, colors, images, etc.) outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath (or willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:). That cell will be reused when you scroll, and if you change the state in the cell class, as you did, that change will show up wherever that cell is reused.

Comment: Rdelmar Hello, thank you for this advice ... in fact it's a bit complicated to work in this way but now I created the whole thing and it would be a nightmare to throw away everything and start over ... I had to make these changes to the custom cell because I created the Swipe Cell ... At this point how can I fix it?

Comment: There is no way to fix it using your current approach. You need to keep track of any state (of cell UI elements) in your data source -- that's the way table views work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rdelmar said, you can only change UI inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

What you should do is give each cell a variable (it could be a boolean). Let's call it color. When the button is clicked, figure out the indexPath of the button that was clicked (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468157/how-can-i-get-the-indexpath-of-uibutton-in-a-customized-tableviewcell)) and modify the cell at that indexPath's color variable (instead of the button's tintColor).

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, get the cell for the current indexPath. Look at that cell's color variable. Depending on its value, change the tintColor accordingly.